# is there any way to increase font size in a text input without it adding space around the outside of the input using css?

Tags: html, css

If I try to increase the font size to fill the input space gets added around the input as if padding is added (although no padding is present in the computed styles in chrome).

How do I stop this as it is making the parent div bigger and then throwing out all the rest of my elements (buttons etc).

Comment: Just set the dimension of the input to be a set height and/or width, which will ignore the font-size.

Comment: Depending on exactly what's going on it might also work to set the line-height

Answer (score 0):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/170/

i made the fontsize larger than the input textbox, but the textbox stays the same height and width (so it wont mess with the dimensions of your div)

```
<input type="text" value="ABCDEFG"/>

input {
    font-size: 29px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: The specific values used mean that parts of many glyphs are cut off, e.g. “j” looks like “i”.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela my example was to prove that this answers OP issue (no matter how much you increase the font-size, the dimensions of the input will not increase/decrease).  If you want the letters to fit, just decrease the font-size